# Conformal mapping from quadrics to the plane

Tags: coordinate-systems, projection, conformal-geometry, quadrics

I am writing a raytracer (a type of 3D engine) to render quadrics, and I am working on rendering a one-sheeted hyperboloid defined by the zero set of  $x^2-y^2+z^2=1$. I need 2D coordinates $a \in [0, 1]$ and $b \in (-\infty, \infty)$ on the surface of the hyperboloid so that I can draw a square grid on its surface.

The aforementioned hyperboloid is the surface of revolution of the rectangular hyperbola  defined by $x^2- y^2=1$. Therefore, it can be parameterized by the following:

$\mathbf{S}(u,v)=\left< \cosh(u)\cos(v), \cosh(u)\sin(v),\sinh(u)\right>$, with $u \in (-\infty, \infty)$ and $v \in [0, 2 \pi]$.

I can thus obtain $u$ and $v$ from a given point $\mathbf{p} = \left<x,y,z\right>$ on the surface, then remapped to the coordinates $a$ and $b$ which lie in the desired ranges:

$a = \frac{1}{2\pi}\left(\pi+\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{z}{x}\right)\right),\\
b = \text{arsinh}(y)$

My thought was that this can be used directly as coordinates for the grid. However, when I implement this in code, the grid cells appear distorted, as in the first image. I would like to get something like the second image.
[image: texture coordinates]
[image: desired outcome]

Specifically, I need a conformal mapping from the aforementioned hyperboloid to the plane.

Also, is there a way to generalize this to other quadrics (i.e. the two-sheeted hyperboloid and paraboloid)?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the conditions on your coordinate system? Since the hyperboloid of one sheet has negative Gaussian curvature, there is no coordinate system that will preserve lengths and areas (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theorema_Egregium). Would you be content with a coordinate mapping that, at each point, distorted lengths in all directions by the same factor? Such a map is called "conformal" and we're guaranteed that such coordinates exist at least locally. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isothermal_coordinates#Isothermal_coordinates_on_surfaces.)

Comment: The problem of finding conformal coordinates such that the constant-coordinate curves ($\{u = a\}$, $\{v = b\}$) are mapped to "latitude and longitude lines" of the hyperboloid is the analogue of the classic problem of computing the Mercator projection, cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection

Comment: A conformal mapping would be more than good enough. If it applies to the other quadrics I mentioned that would be nice too.

Comment: I renamed my post accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The given parameterization already has the favorable property of orthogonality of the coordinates: At each point the coordinate vector fields ${\bf S}_u$ and ${\bf S}_v$ are orthogonal. To find conformal coordinates ${\bf T}(u, v)$, it's enough to rescale the coordinate along the meridians ($u$)---that is, write
$${\bf T}(u, v) = {\bf S}(f(u), v) = (\cosh f(u) \cos 2 \pi v, \cosh f(u) \sin 2 \pi v, \sinh f(u))$$
---so that at each parallel (line of latitude) the scale factors in the $u$ and $v$ directions agree, that is, satisfy $|{\bf T}_u| = |{\bf T}_v|$.

Computing gives that the scale factors are
$$|{\bf T}_u| = |f'(u)| \sqrt{2 \cosh^2 f(u) - 1} \qquad \textrm{and} \qquad |{\bf T}_v| = 2 \pi \cosh f(u),$$
so equating those quantities (and requiring $f'(u) > 0$) gives a separable ordinary differential equation,
$$\frac{\sqrt{2 \cosh^2 f - 1}}{2 \pi \cosh f} df = du ;$$
We may as well impose the symmetry constraint $f(0) = 0$ as a boundary condition.

In summary, finding our conformal parameterization ${\bf T}$ is just a matter of solving this equation.

The left-hand side can be integrated in terms of elementary functions, but it's a little messy.
Substituting $w = \sinh f, dw = \cosh f\,df$ gives
$$\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int \frac{\sqrt{2 \cosh^2 f - 1}}{\cosh f} df = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int \frac{\sqrt{2 w^2 + 1}}{w^2 + 1}\,dw,$$
after which the Euler Substitution $\sqrt{2 w^2 + 1} = y - \sqrt{2} w$ rationalizes the integral:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt 2 \pi} \int \frac{(y^2 + 1)^2 dy}{y (y^4 + 6 y^2 + 1)} .$$
The partial fractions decomposition is favorable,
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt 2 \pi} \int \left(\frac{1}{y} - \frac{4 y}{y^4 + 6 y^2 + 1}\right) \,dy,$$ and the second summand can be evaluated by applying the substitution $z = y^2$ and then using a standard hyperbolic substitution. The result is:
$$u = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \left[\sqrt{2} \operatorname{arsinh} (\sqrt{2} \sinh f) + \operatorname{arcoth}\left(\sqrt{2} \cosh^2 f + \sinh f \sqrt{\cosh 2 f} + \sqrt{2}\right) - \operatorname{arsinh}1\right].$$
It's plausible that the $\operatorname{arcoth}$ term can be simplified, but either way it seems unlikely that $f$ can be expressed explicitly as a function of $u$ in terms of elementary functions.

All that said, as $u \to \pm \infty$, $f$ behaves approximately linearly:
$$f(u) = \sqrt{2} \pi u \pm \frac{\sqrt{2} \operatorname{arsinh} 1 - \log 2}{2} + (\textrm{lower-order terms}) .$$ This behavior shouldn't be surprising, since points with large $u$ are far from the vertices of the generating hyperbola, where the tangent line approximation is very good.

Indeed, replacing $f(u)$ with $\sqrt{2} \pi u$ gives an approximation that is very nearly conformal except in the immediate vicinity of $u = 0$, so that approximation may be adequate for plotting purposes. In the below plot the red curve is the plot of $u$ as a function of $f$, and the blue line is the approximation $f(u) = \sqrt{2} \pi u$.

[image]

The below plot of the hyperboloid uses ${\bf T}$ with the approximation $f(u) = \sqrt 2 \pi u$ with $u \in \left[-\frac12, \frac12\right]$, and gridlines equally spaced in the $uv$-plane ($\Delta u = \Delta v \approx \frac1{20}$).

[image]

The same process to be applied to any surface of revolution using the usual angular and latitude coordinates.